# Key from arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, key

How can I get only Keys from array in PHP
For ex. I have array like below

```
<?php
$array = array(
    "one" => 1,
    "two" => 2,
    "three" => 3,
    "four" => 4
);
```

I want result like below

```
<?php
$array = array(
    "one",
    "two",
    "three",
    "four"
);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use php array keys function:-

```
$array = array(0 => 100, "color" => "red");
print_r(array_keys($array));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => color
)
```

Ref. Link :-- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple `array_keys` PHP function

```
print_r(array_keys($array));
```

or

```
$array = array(
    "one" => 1,
    "two" => 2,
    "three" => 3,
    "four" => 4
);

$somevar = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  $somevar[] = $key;

}

print_r($somevar);
```

Output

```
  Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
    [3] => four
)
```